# How to use influxdb as a datasource for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a usecase where I would like to store conversation (chat) history in influxdb but I would like to have search capability of this textual conversation history, for which I would like to use elasticsearch.

How should I use influxdb as a datasource for elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

Everything needs to be sent to Elasticsearch.
You could create an application which reads all docs from InfluxDb and write to Elasticsearch (using bulk).

Better if possible: in your Application layer, send documents to InfluxDb AND Elasticsearch at the same time.